# Mogodb fetchdata from collection on behalf of date instead of datetime

Tags: mongodb

I want to extract data from collection on basis of date instead of date time which is actually entered in collection i need something like we do in MySQL

```
i.e select * from customer as c where DATE(c.curr_date)="2018-03-10 10:43:23"
```

I want above query to implement in mongodb.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsonendDate = date.getFullYear()+"-"+("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+"T23:59:00.123Z";
var jsonstartDate = date.getFullYear()+"-"+("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+"T00:00:00.123Z";
jsonendDate = new Date(jsonendDate);
jsonstartDate = new Date(jsonstartDate);

db.collection.find({"created_at":{$gte:jsonstartDate,$lte:jsonendDate}},function(err,data){
    console.log(data);

})
```